# How do I save discord messages as HTML

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

So I'm trying to work on a discordpy bot that allows a person to save a message as html. The primary use for this is saving the history of a chat that's important.

I have tried using the python request library but when I do it returns the discord login page's html. It is rather obvious I have to login to get to the actual messages but how I do it and how do I do it without getting into bot users is escaping me. (Not that I would use a bot user)

Here's my code so far

```
import requests

r = requests.get("https://discord.com/channels/@me/ (some channel number) ")
htmlcode=r.text 
f = open("html.txt", "w+")
f.write(htmlcode)
f.close()
```

The return is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport" />

    <!-- section:seometa -->
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Discord" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Discord - A New Way to Chat with Friends & Communities" />
    <meta
      property="og:description"
      content="Discord is the easiest way to communicate over voice, video, and text.  Chat, hang out, and stay close with your friends and communities."
    /><meta property="og:image" content="https://discord.com/assets/ee7c382d9257652a88c8f7b7f22a994d.png" />    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
    <meta name="twitter:site" content="@discord" />
    <meta name="twitter:creator" content="@discord" />
    <!-- endsection -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/0.4fbb9f813ba3219ce3b2.css" integrity="sha256-/WtXWLPiXpC4PGO0HMnvC0mDQRNLLeMJy3zo1VorEYk= sha512-ywifiYWvz/K5ZzPEJmXWGPucqrx6Z8tRZbOM2PvFQOq+c8R9mXTNJbn7H2TlcHrvcMkLCwxzyoejX830M3a+dA=="><link rel="icon" href="/assets/07dca80a102d4149e9736d4b162cff6f.ico" />    <!-- section:title -->
    <title>Discord</title>
    <!-- endsection -->
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app-mount"></div><script nonce="MTM3LDU2LDEyMCwxMjEsMjAyLDE2NywxNjIsMjEw">window.__OVERLAY__ = /overlay/.test(location.pathname)</script><script nonce="MTM3LDU2LDEyMCwxMjEsMjAyLDE2NywxNjIsMjEw">window.__BILLING_STANDALONE__ = /^\/billing/.test(location.pathname)</script><script nonce="MTM3LDU2LDEyMCwxMjEsMjAyLDE2NywxNjIsMjEw">window.GLOBAL_ENV = {
        API_ENDPOINT: '//discord.com/api',
        WEBAPP_ENDPOINT: '//discord.com',
        CDN_HOST: 'cdn.discordapp.com',
        ASSET_ENDPOINT: 'https://discord.com',
        MEDIA_PROXY_ENDPOINT: 'https://media.discordapp.net',
        WIDGET_ENDPOINT: '//discord.com/widget',
        INVITE_HOST: 'discord.gg',
        GUILD_TEMPLATE_HOST: 'discord.new',
        GIFT_CODE_HOST: 'discord.gift',
        RELEASE_CHANNEL: 'stable',
        MARKETING_ENDPOINT: '//discord.com',
        BRAINTREE_KEY: 'production_5st77rrc_49pp2rp4phym7387',
        STRIPE_KEY: 'pk_live_CUQtlpQUF0vufWpnpUmQvcdi',
        NETWORKING_ENDPOINT: '//router.discordapp.net',
        RTC_LATENCY_ENDPOINT: '//latency.discord.media/rtc',
        PROJECT_ENV: 'production',
        REMOTE_AUTH_ENDPOINT: '//remote-auth-gateway.discord.gg',
        SENTRY_TAGS: {"buildId":"060524d","buildType":"normal"},
        MIGRATION_SOURCE_ORIGIN: 'https://discordapp.com',
        MIGRATION_DESTINATION_ORIGIN: 'https://discord.com',
        HTML_TIMESTAMP: Date.now(),
        ALGOLIA_KEY: 'aca0d7082e4e63af5ba5917d5e96bed0',
      };</script><script nonce="MTM3LDU2LDEyMCwxMjEsMjAyLDE2NywxNjIsMjEw">!function(){if(null!=window.WebSocket){var n=function(n){try{var e=localStorage.getItem(n);return null==e?null:JSON.parse(e)}catch(n){return null}},e=n("token"),o=n("gatewayURL");if(e&&o&&!window.__OVERLAY__){var r=null!=window.DiscordNative||null!=window.require?"etf":"json",t=o+"/?encoding="+r+"&v=8&compress=zlib-stream";console.log("[FAST CONNECT] "+t+", encoding: "+r+", version: 8");var a=new WebSocket(t);a.binaryType="arraybuffer";var s=Date.now(),i={open:!1,gateway:t,messages:[]};a.onopen=function(){console.log("[FAST CONNECT] connected in "+(Date.now()-s)+"ms"),i.open=!0},a.onclose=a.onerror=function(){window._ws=null},a.onmessage=function(n){i.messages.push(n)},window._ws={ws:a,state:i}}}}();</script><script src="/assets/986a3ae3929d9e29fe19.js" integrity="sha256-LoDC289vDcG6VM0up3DjkQoYQt5MXSzwzc/o24twba8= sha512-5KLPzgjBUemfWbMw/6Pve4wombvWGRS6xAqe8K6JZIbjSOIZAQ0wngVVZ2Q40skrJktTn8qT6z7fmKpmkuQ5WA=="></script><script src="/assets/3f67d38cb3b30a0a6ed5.js" integrity="sha256-S/IJ2d9zfSFpyvOMPE2vLS3p+AF4hA/nL9NFoKGl1Lw= sha512-NEYu0CVq4TytIOOwKM7dFhQbY2bmcwWtWNLUEMswy7WSz6BVmqc7MUk2z8WrWOfsbcN7EZYD9lFfngFg8d6r8Q=="></script><script src="/assets/e440d0167ba6e2c3bc65.js" integrity="sha256-+5aD7YCYU0yDMOOtoeikXahFfUntTKCF7UorIZVz1+0= sha512-+XEIPmqN3Q0ssS3kVG+eCmWAeWACVulHdYr9piB+blxJAXvsUjxs2RwSMojtngHo7yU6g7Y0XFIaXMM8h10OGA=="></script><script src="/assets/d92c6a6f32d07e5f10ac.js" integrity="sha256-0IhvxMeZPR0wuwzxXyxuol97X8/UDa4q+Z4bVzzaelc= sha512-x/Tboie3TQtrgEOjC58NS8AiAbgTNRIZ1ZiTHtdpd0cRPgjy93yJf8PZ9VU0u9Lbe3a5zbCmF3o92ZHZLcjgBA=="></script>  </body>
</html>
```

If someone could give me a pointer in the right direction, I would be ingratiated.

Comment: You've tagged [tag:discord.py] but you're not actually leveraging it - care to elaborate on the tag choice? To the content of your question: why not actually use Discord.py and retrieve the contents of a channel through the API? What did you actually expect `requests` to return? It's not logged in as any user, how would it return anything except the login page when trying to navigate to a channel? If you're dead-set on automating a browser, have you researched Selenium Webdriver or a similar testing-esque suite to perform rudimentary interface traversal for the login portion?